# Calculate homography by two parrallel lines

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, homography, perspectivecamera

I know two lines

```
  （in the form Ai x'+Bi y'+ Ci =0）
```

on the image, which is a pair of parallel line

```
（in the form x = ki）
```

on a real word plane（just like a pair of road traffic marking line).
How can I know the homography relationship that transform the image point （x',y'）to the coordinate (x) of the real world plane.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only two lines ?
Otherwise, you could compute homographies from [vanishing points](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00001038/document) if you have enough parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D homography is defined by four known lines in general configuration (i.e. no three intersecting in a single point).

A known line gives the same amount of information as a known point. Both are represented as homogeneous three-vectors. A recommended book: Multiple View Geometry by Hartley & Zisserman.